# Uniqueness of Characterstic Functions in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29), a characteristic function completely determines the properties of a probability distribution. This means it must be unique. However, the definition given is:

$$
\text{Char of }X (t)=E[e^itX]$$

Now $e^{iz}$ repeats for every $2 \pi$ increase in $z$. So how can it be unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought at first you were asking how the characteristic function can be unique. There's no issue here, because e^ix is a well-defined function: for a given value of x, there is a unique value of e^ix. And so the expectation (an integral) has a unique value as well.

On second thought, it appears you're asking how it's possible, considering that e^ix is not *injective* (i.e., multiple x can have the same value of e^ix), that the original distribution can be completely recovered from the characteristic function. The answer to *that* is that you're probably missing the "t" in the expression: the characteristic function is a function of t, and although for a *given* value of t (e.g. t=1), the random variables $X$ and $X+2k\pi/t$ *would* have the same value of the characteristic function at that point, they would have different values at other t. So the characteristic *functions* are different, and yes, the distribution can be completely recovered from the characteristic function.

Comment: Okay, so thats why my reasoning is wrong. I don't suppose you know how to prove that no two probabilities distributions have the same characteristic function?

Comment: As a first step, note that you can recover all the moments from the characteristic function: the derivative of the characteristic function E[e^(itX)] is E[iXe^(itX)]=iE[X] at t=0, the second derivative gives -E[X^2], etc. And you can also recover the actual distribution itself, see the section on inversion formulas at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas

Comment: BTW: when the distribution has a density function, the characteristic function is just the Fourier transform and vice-versa, so for most continuous random variables you encounter, a simpler reason is: take the [inverse] Fourier transform of the characteristic function and you get the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a Fourier transform. E(x) is an integral over the probability distribution. The function is unique; if you focus on the value inside the expectation integral, that's not, but so what?